# How to trigger submit using jQuery Form when button is not rendered using type=submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-plugins, file-upload

Given this form

```
<form id="posts_form">
    <input type="file" value="" name="picture" >

    <span class="picture_js fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">
        <span class="fc-button-inner">
            <span class="fc-button-content save_button">Share</span>
            <span class="fc-button-effect">
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</form>
```

I'm using this `<span>` based button for style purposes.

What I'm trying to do is bind a click event on the `<span>` button and fire a submit function, like:

```
$('.picture_js').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    pictureUpload();
    return false;
});

function pictureUpload() {

        var options = { url: 'chat/upload' }

    $('#posts_form').ajaxForm(options);
}
```

But there is no response to clicking on the button (no errors on console either) -- any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: I don't see any 'posts_form' element in your html, is this the whole of the html?

Comment: sorry @iforce2d - just corrected the code and added id to the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to include and implement both `beforeSubmit` and `success` options for file upload to work, as suggested in this post:
[Jquery form plugin file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302344/jquery-form-plugin-file-upload).

Try this:

```
function pictureUpload() {

    var options = { 
        url: 'chat/upload',
        success: function() {},
        beforeSubmit: function() {}
    }

    $('#posts_form').ajaxForm(options);
}
```